# Issue with Intent.ACTION_SEND?

Tags: android, android-intent

```
    eTSubject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTSubject);
eTContent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTContent);
subject = eTSubject.getText().toString();
content = eTContent.getText().toString();

    iBMail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            i.setType("plain/text");

            i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                    new String[] { "" });

            i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);

            i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content);

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Continue with send?"));
        }
    });
```

Above is my piece of code, which is trying to send email with some text i'm tryin to put in email screen and amazingly not getting that content when email screen is opening. Anyone have any idea why is it not working?

Any help will highly be appreciated.

mrana..

Answer (score 0):

Guys i have solved this issue. If any of you are facing such kinda issue then all you have to do is to put your string variable where you are getting the text and changing the edittext into string within your click method which you are triggering from the view by pressing any widget.